# Change the layout margins of a UITableViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

The first image is how my cells are currently and the second image is how I want them to be. I have a UITableViewController and want to programmatically change the layout margins however it does not work

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Gray")
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Gray")
    tableView.contentInset.top = .padding
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.register(TaskCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "taskCell")
    tableView.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20) // Does not work
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should put all item in a `UIVIew()` Then give margin to this view to cell contentView.

Comment: @Kudos The items are already in a [contentView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview) but changes to the layoutMargins don't work when the tableView loads

Comment: No. I mean all Items should be in another view and that view is in ContentView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a UIView inside the cell as background view and give margins to that view by adjusting its size in the storyboard. Then change the colour opacity of the cell's content view to 0

[image]

Comment: All the labels and images are in a [contentView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview) so I can change the frame size which would work. So I just ignore the layoutMargins property?

Comment: You need to add a new view inside the contentView and then add all the labels and images should be add in side the new view. We can change the frame of the new view.